# Android Fragments sharing info ways

Tags: android, theory

i have a internal discussion about what way is better to share info between fragments contents inside a controller activity. In a first classical way, you can set arguments when you are going to replace fragments as follows:

```
                //Just now i'm inside Fragment 1 and i'll navigate to Fragment 2
                Fragment newFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Fragment2.TAG);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putBoolean("test1", true);

                // Create new fragment and transaction
                if(newFragment==null)
                    newFragment = Fragment2.newInstance(b);

                 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)//.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim)
                            .replace(R.id.fragment_place, newFragment, Fragment2.class.getName())
                            .addToBackStack(newFragment.getClass().getName())
                            .commit();
```

The newInstace method does as i meant above, so, with setArguments:

```
    public static Fragment2 newInstance(Bundle arguments){
    Fragment2 f = new Fragment2();
    if(arguments != null){
        f.setArguments(arguments);
    }
    return f;
}
```

But Fragment1 and Fragment2 they are both inside a ControllerActivity, so i can also think about a second way to share information obtained in Fragment1 towards Fragment2, through declaring attributes in the ControllerActivity, so i could do (declaring previously an object in the activity) as follows inside any fragment:

**EDIT**

```
public class ControllerActivity extends FragmentActivity{

int value = 5;
...
```

And then, inside my fragment:

```
((SplashActivity)getActivity()).value = 10; //i can assign or recover value when i desire
```

My question is what inconveniences would have doing as the second way.

Comment: will you use async operations in your app, which can change Activity values?

Comment: Do you mean `inter-fragment communication`?

Comment: The only evil I know of in this way, is the demons Static variables unleash! Having said that I cannot resist using them.

Comment: @Paritosh of course, i mean inter-fragment communication in a way that you can use the Activity to swing the objects between fragments.

Comment: @Skynet in fact i am declaring non static variables and i get the values as i mentioned.

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html and https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDgQtwIwBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DVyyGP_d0Ia8&ei=VgJSVcXHMI-cugTxhIHICg&usg=AFQjCNF5XeLcgw-DfTULky7BtIo9UQMM1A&bvm=bv.92885102,d.c2E The video will explain you in details about inter-fragment communication

Comment: @Paritosh i've liked the video, it's very usefull, the key is using an interface, indeed i've used them in several apps. Anyway...i can not see the inconvenience of accessing variables in my 2nd way, they are non statics and the access is fast and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing code using 2nd way is fast. But the problem is you have to cast the general `Activity` to the more specific `SplashActivity` in which the `value` variable exists. If you want to use the Fragment with another Activity, or you want a Fragment to be a general purpose UI component you have to use `interface` for passing the data.

As mentioned in comments, bellow links provide more details about `interface/callback` method:

- [android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)
- [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyyGP_d0Ia8) from [slidenerd](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbP2HeYGC3kfHjHLMPplZuQ)

Hope this answers your question.